# Normalize ember-data payload in normalizePayload, but "type" is null

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to write code to generically normalize embedded records. I'm trying to do this in the "normalizePayload" method of the serializer, as "extractObject" and "extractArray" don't get called on a store.pushPayload call (I'm pre-loading data using pushPayload).

Here's my code:

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.reopen
    embeddedRelationships: []

    extractHasOne: (payload, relationship_name) ->
        object = payload[relationship_name]
        objectId = object['id']
        payload["#{relationship_name}_id"] = objectId
        delete payload[relationship_name]

        return object

    extractHasMany: (payload, relationship_name) ->
        objects = payload[relationship_name]
        objectIds = objects.mapProperty('id')
        payload["#{Ember.Inflector.inflector.singularize(relationship_name)}_ids"] = objectIds
        delete payload[relationship_name]

        return objects

    extractRelationships: (payload) ->
        extracted_objects = {}

        this.embeddedRelationships.forEach((relationship_name) ->
            relationship_payload = payload[relationship_name]
            if relationship_payload instanceof Object
                # has one
                extracted_objects[relationship_name] = this.extractHasOne(relationship_payload, relationship_name)
            else if relationship_payload instanceof Array
                # has many
                extracted_objects[relationship_name] = this.extractHasMany(relationship_payload, relationship_name)
        , this)

        return extracted_objects

    normalizePayload: (type, payload) ->
        if payload[type]?
            # single object
            this.extractRelationships(payload[type])
        else if payload[Ember.Inflector.inflector.pluralize(type)]?
            # many objects
            payload[Ember.Inflector.inflector.pluralize(type)].forEach((object_payload) ->
                this.extractRelationships(object_payload)
            , this)
```

NOTE: this isn't done yet, as I'm not merging all the extracted objects and sideloading them yet.

In either case, the idea is that in a subclass, I override "embedded relationships" with a list of strings that represent the relationships that must be normalized for that model.

The problem I'm running into is simple: "normalizePayload" is being called with a null "type" value.

I'm pre-loading the data like so:

```
this.store.pushPayload('category', window.preloadCategories)
```

Is this an ember bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20501564/normalize-embedded-records-with-ember-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pushPayload` takes the type and grabs that `serializer` then it calls `pushPayload` on the custom serializer which doesn't take a type, so no type is passed into the `normalizePayload`.

I'd suggest creating a custom serializer for `Category` instead of `Application`, then you'll know its a category type.

The reason behind this was pushPayload was geared to pushing more than a single type (aka the payload isn't just `Category` or `Post`

### pushPayload on the store

````
  /**
    Push some raw data into the store.

    The data will be automatically deserialized using the
    serializer for the `type` param.

    This method can be used both to push in brand new
    records, as well as to update existing records.

    You can push in more than one type of object at once.
    All objects should be in the format expected by the
    serializer.

    ```js
    App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer;

    var pushData = {
      posts: [
        {id: 1, post_title: "Great post", comment_ids: [2]}
      ],
      comments: [
        {id: 2, comment_body: "Insightful comment"}
      ]
    }

    store.pushPayload('post', pushData);
    ```

    @method pushPayload
    @param {String} type
    @param {Object} payload
  */

  pushPayload: function (type, payload) {
    var serializer;
    if (!payload) {
      payload = type;
      serializer = defaultSerializer(this.container);
      Ember.assert("You cannot use `store#pushPayload` without a type unless your default serializer defines `pushPayload`", serializer.pushPayload);
    } else {
      serializer = this.serializerFor(type);
    }
    serializer.pushPayload(this, payload);
  },
````

### pushPayload on the serializer

```
    It will first normalize the payload, so you can use this to push
    in data streaming in from your server structured the same way
    that fetches and saves are structured.

    @method pushPayload
    @param {DS.Store} store
    @param {Object} payload
  */
  pushPayload: function(store, payload) {
    payload = this.normalizePayload(null, payload);

    for (var prop in payload) {
      var typeName = this.typeForRoot(prop),
          type = store.modelFor(typeName);

      /*jshint loopfunc:true*/
      var normalizedArray = map.call(payload[prop], function(hash) {
        return this.normalize(type, hash, prop);
      }, this);

      store.pushMany(typeName, normalizedArray);
    }
  },
```

Comment: Hmm I see. I already have it working fine if I override pushPayload on Category, though. The whole point of my adventure here with ApplicationSerializer is to try to make the whole thing generic (several of my models have embedded payloads, so my code wouldn't be very DRY). Is there any other way to do what I want?

Comment: Hi I just came across this, and have the same problem that I want a generic pushPayload funcitonality. My generic serializer is already extracting relations etc, since not all my data comes sideloaded. I tried your serializer.pushPayload but it tells me that "map is not defined", Unfortunately im not a JS pro in order to find out what it needs to be